# Why does the following not set up citations in Harvard style?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to get Harvard citation style, but this keeps using numbering.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{natbib}


\bibliographystyle{dcu}

\begin{document}

\cite{xx}

\bibliography{a}


\end{document}
```

Also, how do I ensure the order in the bib follows last name order?

Comment: Fixed by using \documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle} - I thought it was enough to do it in natbib, but that's not the case when using elsarticle.

Answer (score 1):

`elsarticle` already loads `natbib`, unless instructed otherwise with the `nonatbib` option. What's more, `elsarticle` loads `natbib` with the `number` option by default – again unless instructed otherwise with the document class option `authoryear`.

So

```
\documentclass[authoyryear]{elsarticle}

\bibliographystyle{dcu}

\begin{document}
\cite{incollection-full}

\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

would tell `elsarticle` to prepare author-year citations. When I run that MWE, however, I get two error messages

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.1 \harvardpreambledefs
>                         {%
> ? 
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.4 \harvardpreambletext
>                         {%
> ?
> ```

That is because te `dcu` bibliography style is part of the [`harvard` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/harvard) and should be used together with `\usepackage{harvard}`. But the `harvard` package can't be loaded with with `natbib`, so we need

```
\documentclass[nonatbib]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{harvard}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}

\begin{document}
\cite{incollection-full}

\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Interestingly [`har2nat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/har2nat) instead of `harvard` is not enough here.

---

But if you are using `elsarticle` you should probably use one of *their* bibliography styles and not some random other style, so

```
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\begin{document}
\cite{incollection-full}

\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

would be a *much* better idea.